# Unable to open for write windows error: The storage control block address is invalid

Tags: php, html, windows, http, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4Xnc.png)Hi there I'm creating some kind of page to upload picture title and description. I still try to run it locally.  All seems works fine but when I try to upload things, there's error message like this : /uploads\popup\1673830478976_thumbnail.jpeg: unable to open for write windows error: The storage control block address is invalid.

I already browse some option to fix my problem and none of them work. So far all advice I could find is to troubleshoot, clean but, and reinstall the windows. But none of them seems work. I also try downgrading my windows from 11 to 10 and try moving my main file to other drive and set it up all over again but still the same. And I don't really thing there's problem with the code because it work just fine in my seniors computer (since I only clone it from git for study purpose). I guess the problem is in my Laptop and I'm hopping someone help me find a way to fix it. And if someone want to see the code because there's a chance that the problem might be there let me know.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why is the path shown in your error message starting with a slash - on a windows system?